# Why is the boolean "OR" operator denoted as "+"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

I learnt boolean algebra as part of a computer hardware course where the focus was very much on using it as a foundation for creating digital logic blocks out of gates, so there was very early on introduced a mapping between the boolean values `True` and `False` with the numerals `1` and `0`.

In a ring consisting of the set $\{0,1\}$ and operations $\cdot$  and $\oplus$ as modulu 2 product and sum respectively, there's a correspondence between the behavior of $\{0,1\}$ under $\cdot$ and $\oplus$ with the logical values $\{\text{False, True}\}$ under the logical connective $\text{AND}$ and $\text{XOR}$ respectively.

I can see why we might feel comfortable mapping the boolean values to "binary digits", and map $\text{AND}$ to the product $\cdot$, and $\text{XOR}$ to the sum $\oplus$. I'm failing to see any connection between the logical $\text{OR}$ with anything resembling the arithmetic sum $+$? In what setting would we be able to have $1+1=1$, so that it corresponds to $\text{TRUE}\lor\text{TRUE}=\text{TRUE}$?

Is it just by convention that $\text{OR}$ is usually denoted with $+$ in boolean algebra, or is there some way of motivating it?

Comment: Any of $X$ or $Y$ being equal to $1$ in the algebraic expression $X+Y$ results in a value not equal to $0$ (true), while $X \cdot Y \ne 0$ only when neither of $X$ and $Y$ are zero.

Comment: This notation $\cdot$ and $+$ was used by Boole himself.  For some reason, in the 1800's he did not think of making his notation compatible with digital computers.

Comment: Using $\cdot$ and $+$ for AND and OR makes one of the distributive properties look pretty familiar: $$A\;\text{AND}\;(B\;\text{OR}\;C) = (A\;\text{AND}\;B)\;\text{OR}\;(A\;\text{AND}\;C) \quad\to\quad A\cdot(B+C)=(A\cdot B)+(A\cdot C)$$ (although it makes the other one look *weird*).

Comment: @GEDgar I'm well aware that boolean algebra was formulated well before computer technology was a widespread thing. Nevertheless, if he chose to denote the logical $\lor$ with a $+$ I'm curious if there was a motivation behind that choice.

Comment: @RasmusKällqvist: For Boole's motivation, perhaps you should ask this question of the [History of Science and Math StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Because [George Boole](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#OperLawsForElecSymb) in 1847 used $+$ for "logical sum" and juxtaposition for "logical product".

Comment: See [Boolean Logic (1847)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#OperLawsForElecSymb): "The first operation Boole introduced was the *multiplication* $xy$ of symbols. When one switches to using classes, the corresponding multiplication of two classes results in their intersection. The first law was the distributive law $x(u+v)=xu+xv$,
where Boole said that $u+v$ corresponded to dividing a class into two parts." Thus $x+y$  is the union of $x$ and $y$ provided $x$ and $y$ are disjoint classes.

Answer (score 0):

Logical disjunction ($\lor$) is naturally associated with the union ($\cup$) of sets. If there's any way to define $+$ on sets, it would be $\cup$.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I'm in particular looking at the connection between logical connectives and representing them with something resembling arithmetic operations here. I don't know if sets need to be directly involved, even if they are connected.

Comment: @RasmusKällqvist Sets are only revelant because of a proposition-set isomorphism. If it's any consolation, they don't need to be sets formally studied. "The set of ways a proposition can be true" is enough for the proposition-set correspondence to work. Elementary schools' Venn diagrams, with two overlapping circles comprising a pretzel-like shape, is all there is to $+$ here.